# How to change size of the indicator of ttk::checkbutton and ttk::radiobutton

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to change the size of the indicator of a ttk::checkbutton combined with the clam theme. If I use the default theme I can change the size by the option *indicatordiameter*, but this doesn't work with the clam theme. The same problem occurs with ttk::radiobutton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different issues with themes.

a) Different themes use different configuration options.

b) Graphical themes cannot resize their graphical elements.

For the clam theme, you will need to configure the style's `-indicatorsize`.

```
% package require Tk
8.6.9
% ttk::style theme use clam
% ttk::radiobutton .a -text hello
.a
% pack .a
% ttk::style configure A.TRadiobutton -indicatorsize 20
% ttk::radiobutton .b -text hello -style A.TRadiobutton
.b
% pack .b
%
```